# Как показать случайные числа по возрастанию на reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Создаю аналог игры лото на react. При нажатии на кнопку должны выпадать случайные числа и числа которые выпали не должны повторяться. Но числа должны идти по возрастанию от меньшего к большему. Не могу придумать как это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста если есть идеи.
Рендер приложения

```
import { Component } from "react";
import Number from "./number/number";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
  };
  randomNumbers = () => {
      let numbers = (this.state.numbers).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
      let number = numbers[0];
      const index = numbers.indexOf(number);
      if (index > -1) {
        numbers.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.setState({number: index})
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <button className='button' onClick={this.randomNumbers}>New numbers</button>
      <div className='wrapper'>
      <Number number={this.state.numbers[0]} />
      <Number number={this.state.numbers[1]} />
      <Number number={this.state.numbers[2]} />
      <Number number={this.state.numbers[3]} />
      <Number number={this.state.numbers[4]} />
      </div>
      </div>
      );
    }    
  };  
  export default App;
```

Рендер его компонента

```
import { React } from 'react';
import './number.css';
const Number = props => {
    return (
        <div className='wrapper_number'>
            <div className='number'>{props.number}</div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default Number;
```

И стили

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.button{
    margin: 50px 43%;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper_number{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.number{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Сделайте отдельный массив для чисел, которые выпали. Этот массив сортируйте и потом уже выводите компонент Number, а чтобы проверить числа на уникальность, просто проверяете есть ли такое число уже в массив с числами, которые выпали

Comment: Что значит случайные числа по возрастанию? То есть каждое следующее число должно быть случайным но больше предыдущего ?

Comment: да. Т.е. если у первого числа выпадет 9, у второго должно быть больше 9, а у третьего больше чем число второго и так далее...